# Sort part of an array of array structs C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'd like to sort part of an array of array of structs in C#. I don't want to implement the IComparer interface as that seems to involve boxing and there doesn't seem to be a proper Array.Sort variant that would let me define a lambda expression to compare two elements.

My struct:

```
    private struct ActionChainBlock
    {
        public int optionIndex;
        public Vector2I target;
        public int fitness;
    }
```

My array:

```
    private readonly ActionChainBlock[][] chains;
```

My code thus far:

```
        System.Array.Sort(chains, (x, y) =>
        {
            var xFitness = CalculateFitnessSum(x);
            var yFitness = CalculateFitnessSum(y);

            return -xFitness.CompareTo(yFitness);
        });
```

What I would like to do but can't:

```
        System.Array.Sort(chains, indexStart, indexEnd, (x, y) =>
        {
            var xFitness = CalculateFitnessSum(x);
            var yFitness = CalculateFitnessSum(y);

            return -xFitness.CompareTo(yFitness);
        });
```

The CalculateFitnessSum() takes a ActionChainBlock[] as the argument.
What's the most performant way to do this?

EDIT:

Couldn't do it with a lambda expression so I implemented the Comparer class:

```
    private class ActionChainBlockComparer : IComparer<ActionChainBlock[]>
    {
        public int Compare(ActionChainBlock[] x, ActionChainBlock[] y)
        {
            var xFitness = CalculateFitnessSum(x);
            var yFitness = CalculateFitnessSum(y);

            return -xFitness.CompareTo(yFitness);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need details.  Sorting without seeing the data is impossible.

Comment: Isn't there an overload that is generic? Something like `Array.Sort<T>(T[] array, int index, int length, IComparer<T> comparer)`?

Comment: `IComparer` will involve boxing, but `IComparer<T>` should not.

Comment: It's actually an array of arrays of structs, I updated the question.

Comment: Do you want to sort each inner array then? If not, then regardless of boxing or not, this question is unclear. Please elaborate on how you want to sort an array of arrays of structs.

Comment: Well, if it's the outer array you want to sort then boxing is not an issue because arrays are reference types. If it's the inner arrays, then [`Sort<T>(T[], Int32, Int32, IComparer<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort__1___0___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___0__) will not use boxing.

Comment: Added more details to my post.

Comment: So you don't want to sort structs, you want to sort arrays? Then boxing is not an issue.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Array.Sort uses them?

Comment: You say you can't use the last example, why not?

Comment: Simply implement the comparison as `IComparer<ActionChainBlock[]>` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Yes, but `Array.Sort` uses the extra parameters to limit the sort range, so the parameters do matter.

Comment: My current code uses System.Comparison<ActionChainBlock[]>.

Comment: If you want it fast then the most important detail is that you don't have to use CalculateFitnessSum() in the comparison.  Too expensive, Sort() visits an element multiple times.  Do this up front, before you sort.  That does require a smarter structure so you can store the sum, somewhat inevitably that now probably ought to be a class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Linq.

```
using System.Linq;
```

then you can just do this:

```
chains.OrderBy(x => x.Sum(y => y.fitness));
```

or use where and any other Linq operation.

if you want to sort only part of the arrays use the where to pick the relevant arrays.